# What are the command-line options for un-tarring a tar.gz file to a specific directory?

Tags: gzip, tar

This is one of those things I don't quite do often enough to memorize.  I thought it would be nice to have the answer here so I (and maybe others with as poor a memory as me) can star it.

What command-line options to I use to un-tar a tar.gz file into a specific directory, on Linux?

Comment: You can't even memorise "man tar"?

Comment: @John, as an infrequent *nix user, I despise the `man` pages on the occasions when I'm forced to read them. Most of them read like you already have a comp-sci degree, or you already know the intracacies of their software (in which case you're just after a refresher, not a learning experience)

Comment: @Farseeker, I won't argue what you said about man pages (I probably use *nix less that you do) but given the choice of using man or remembering a URL to a page with the same info I know where I'll turn first.

Comment: I've found that every time I ask a question here (no matter how easy it is to look up the answer somewhere else) I learn something.  This time, so far, I learned about the multiple v method for specifying "verbosity".

Comment: John, now we've created a web page that may show up on a Google search for *nix newbies who wouldn't necessarily even know to try `man tar`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tar xzf file.tgz -C directory
```

But directory must be created before you can fill it
If you don't define -C, it is extract in the current directory

Answer (score 0):

From `man tar`:

```
   tar -xvvzf foo.tar.gz
          extract gzipped foo.tar.gz
```

Comment: I don't understand why -v is specified twice.  Is that a typo?

Comment: -v : just the names of the files
-vv : names + informations like size, owner, rights...

Comment: many commands use the multiple v method for defining just how verbose you want to be, the more vs, the more detail is displayed. the upper limit depends on each program though.